# Using Script.Head() in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syntax, orchardcms

I'm trying to insert a a javascript file I wrote (just a simple alert box) into the header of my Orchard CMS site. My problem is that I can't get the pathing right to lead to the .js file, I've even tried placing my .js file in the website root folder.

Any ideas how to get the path right?

Comment: What makes you say you don't have the right path?

Comment: I check on the rendered HTML and the line for the script I inserted has a 404 error inside, although it does show on the page itself...

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you are probably missing a web config in the directory where the script is.